How to convert the first image below to SVG?
<img src="https://i.sstatic.net/4aAJ8aiL.jpg" width="100" height="100">
<img src="https://i.sstatic.net/A2uCeTn8.png" width="100" height="100">
<img src="https://i.sstatic.net/xV7aYmsi.jpg" width="100" height="100">
As title,The first picture should be a combination of the patterns of the second and third pictures. the second picture already has an svg version on the wiki but there seems to be a problem. I found the svg repair version,


<svg width="21.17" height="21.17" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" height="2.6" width="2.6" y="-0.8" x="-0.8" id="b">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1.667" />
    </filter>
    <linearGradient id="a" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#1c0000" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="white" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <title>Layer 1</title>
    <g id="svg_1" paint-order="normal" stroke-width="0.265" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="#7dd32a">
      <path id="svg_2" fill="url(#a)" d="m10.736,0.133a10.451,10.451 0 0 0 -7.543,3.06a10.451,10.451 0 0 0 0,14.78a10.451,10.451 0 0 0 14.78,0a10.451,10.451 0 0 0 0,-14.78a10.451,10.451 0 0 0 -7.237,-3.06z" />
      <path id="svg_3" fill="none" d="m10.583,4.366a6.218,6.218 0 0 0 -6.218,6.217a6.218,6.218 0 0 0 6.218,6.218a6.218,6.218 0 0 0 6.218,-6.218a6.218,6.218 0 0 0 -6.218,-6.217z" />
      <path id="svg_4" fill="none" d="m10.583,8.599a1.984,1.984 0 0 0 -1.984,1.984a1.984,1.984 0 0 0 1.984,1.985a1.984,1.984 0 0 0 1.984,-1.985a1.984,1.984 0 0 0 -1.984,-1.983l0,-0.001z" />
    </g>
    <path id="svg_5" paint-order="normal" filter="url(#b)" fill="#7dd32a" d="m33.5,68.5a2.5,2.5 0 0 0 -2.5,2.5a2.5,2.5 0 0 0 2.5,2.5a2.5,2.5 0 0 0 2.5,-2.5a2.5,2.5 0 0 0 -2.5,-2.5zm32.5,-28a2.5,2.5 0 0 0 -2.5,2.5a2.5,2.5 0 0 0 2.5,2.5a2.5,2.5 0 0 0 2.5,-2.5a2.5,2.5 0 0 0 -2.5,-2.5zm-38,3a2.5,2.5 0 0 0 -2.5,2.5a2.5,2.5 0 0 0 2.5,2.5a2.5,2.5 0 0 0 2.5,-2.5a2.5,2.5 0 0 0 -2.5,-2.5zm-12,-16a2.5,2.5 0 0 0 -2.5,2.5a2.5,2.5 0 0 0 2.5,2.5a2.5,2.5 0 0 0 2.5,-2.5a2.5,2.5 0 0 0 -2.5,-2.5zm26,-20a2.5,2.5 0 0 0 -2.5,2.5a2.5,2.5 00 0 2.5,2.5a2.5,2.5 0 0 0 2.5,-2.5a2.5,2.5 0 0 0 -2.5,-2.5z" transform="scale(.26458)" />
  </g>
</svg>



but the effect is different from the first one, and the background of the first picture is not white but transparent.

I'm afraid you can't do do this directly in svg as it doesn't have conic-gradients. However there are some JS libraries that can emulate these like 'gradient-path'. See also 'Can I apply a gradient along an SVG path?'

I saw the svg with conic-gradients from the freesvg website (https://freesvg.org/cgrd3)
